# I cannot make .ISO file

Tags: operating-system, iso

While I'm trying to make hangman.bin to .iso using `mkisofs`:
`mkisofs -o hangman.iso -b hangman.bin ./`

It shows me this error:

> Setting input-charset to 'UTF-8' from locale.
> /cdrtools/mkisofs: './hangman.iso' is the archive. Not dumped.
> Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> /cdrtools/mkisofs: Error - boot image './hangman.bin' has not an allowable size.